# How to find $\int \ln^nx\space dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How does one evaluate a function in the form of
$$\int \ln^nx\space dx$$
My trusty friend Wolfram Alpha is blabbering about $\Gamma$ functions and I am having trouble following. Is there a method for indefinitely integrating such and expression? Or if there isn't a method how would you tackle the problem?

Comment: By $\ln^nx$ do you mean $(\ln x)^n$ or $\ln(\ln(\ldots(\ln(x))\ldots))$?

Comment: Try doing a little induction, with the particular cases $\,n=1,2,3\;$ . Remember: $$\int\log x\,dx=x\log x-x$$

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud The standard notation for $(\ln x)^n$

Comment: An exponential generating function for the coefficients of the powers of the logarithms is $\dfrac {e^x}{1+xy}=1+(1-y)\frac {x^1}{1!}+(1-2y+2y^2)\frac {x^2}{2!}+(1-3y+6y^2-6y^3)\frac {x^3}{3!}+\cdots$ as found at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A008279) (for example $\int \log^3(x)\;dx=x(\log^3(x)-3\log^2(x)+6\log(x)-6)$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let 
$$F_n=\int \log^n(x) dx$$
so by integration by parts (we derivate $\log^n(x)$) we have
$$F_n=x\log^n(x)-n\int\log^{n-1}(x)dx=x\log^n(x)-nF_{n-1}$$
so we find $F_n$ by induction by the relation:

$$\left\{\begin{array}\\
F_0=x+C\\
F_{n}=x\log^n(x)-nF_{n-1},\quad n\geq 1
\end{array}\right.$$

**Added**$\ $ We can write a simple procedure with Maple which gives the expression of $F_n$ for every $n$ as follow:

> [image]

We can prove by induction that
$$F_n=x\log^n(x)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-k}\frac{n!}{k!} x\log^k(x)+(-1)^nx+C$$

Comment: So would this be correct?
$$F_n=x\ln^nx+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[-(k+1)\ln^kx \right]+C$$

Comment: I don't think your formula is correct and you can verify this by calculating $F_1$ and $F_2$.

Comment: prim(1) is false as you said it should be $x\ln(x)-x+C$

Comment: Notice that $C$ is an arbitrary constant so replace $C$ by $-C$ isn't a problem.

Comment: Ah okay, Along the lines of finite series' is my interpretation close to the right answer?

Comment: I edited my answer and I gave a closed form of $F_n$.

Comment: I still don't understand the closed form of $F_n$ could you explain in further detail the way you inducted it?

Comment: Nice work, as usual!

Answer (score 5):

If $\ln^nx$ denotes $\log(x)^n$, then my hint is to try the simple substitution $e^y = x$, giving
$$\int\log(x)^ndx = \int y^ne^ydy$$

Answer (score 3):

Write $x=e^y$, and $\text{d}x=e^y\text{d}y$, and integrate by parts a few times $$\int \ln^n(x)\text{d}x\text=\int y^{n}e^{y}\text{d}y=y^ne^y-n\int y^{n-1}e^y\text{d}y.$$

Answer (score 1):

I notice these answers do not also explain why Wolfram Alpha gives results involving the gamma function. I'll provide that here.

The reason is that Wolfram Alpha interprets $n$ as an arbitrary *real or complex number*, not just a nonnegative integer. In that case, there is no elementary solution and we have to use the gamma function.

This works as follows: Start

$$\int \ln(x)^n dx,\ n \in \mathbb{C}$$

and use the substitution $u = \ln(x)$, $du = \frac{1}{x} dx$ to get

$$\int \ln(x)^n dx = \int \ln(x)^n \frac{x}{x} dx = \int x \ln(x)^n \frac{1}{x} dx = \int e^u u^n du$$.

Now the last integral is essentially that for the gamma function. In particular, using the "lower incomplete gamma function"

$$\gamma(s, x) = \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t} t^{s-1} dt$$

we have the last integral (with one more change of variable $u \rightarrow -v$) as

$$\begin{align}\int e^u u^n du &= -\int e^{-v} (-v)^n dv = -(-1)^n \int e^{-v} v^n dv \\ &= -(-1)^n \gamma(n+1, v) + C \\ &= -(-1)^n \gamma(n+1, -u) + C\end{align}$$

And thus the final integral is

$$\int \ln(x)^n dx = (-1)^{n+1} \gamma(n+1, -\ln(x)) + C$$.

There is then a recurrence formula

$$\gamma(s, x) = (s - 1)\gamma(s - 1, x) - e^{-x} x^{s-1}$$

for the incomplete gamma, which can be used to get Sami Ben Romdhane's solution for $n$ natural. But this formula is obtained by integration by parts on the incomplete gamma, so it would be simpler to just apply that directly to the original integral, as he did, unless you do need the answer for a non-integer $n$ in terms of standard, though not elementary, functions.