# Find $\int\ln^{n} x$ .

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, logarithms, constants

> Find $\int\ln^{n} x$ .

My observation

$\int\ln^{1} x= x(\ln x- 1)+ constant$

$\int\ln^{2} x= x(\ln^{2} x- 2\ln x+ 2)+ constant$

$\int\ln^{3} x= x(\ln^{3} x- 3\ln^{2} x+ 6\ln x- 6)+ constant$

$\int\ln^{4} x= x(\ln^{4} x- 4\ln^{3} x+ 12\ln^{2} x- 24\ln x+ 24)+ constant$

$$\ddots$$

We have

$$\ddots$$

$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\ln x} (\ln^{4} x- 4\ln^{3} x+ 12\ln^{2} x- 24\ln x+ 24)= 4(\ln^{3} x- 3\ln^{2} x+ 6\ln x- 6)$

$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\ln x} (\ln^{3} x- 3\ln^{2} x+ 6\ln x- 6)= 3(\ln^{2} x- 2\ln x+ 2)$

$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\ln x} (\ln^{2} x- 2\ln x+ 2)= 2(\ln x- 1)$

I used these to prep for my tests, thanks!

Comment: See [How to find $\int \ln^nx\space dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/459428/9464)

Comment: "How can I use these for my problem?" Instead of simply writing out the results for $n=1,2,3,4$, it may be more useful to think about *how* you got the results. For instance, did integration by parts tell you a recursive formula?

Comment: My question is actually better in terms of context ... I want you could leave it alone ! Please !

Comment: @KBDave Can you unmark duplicate? I posted it because I want to see another approachs, I'm so sorry, I didn't notice the duplicate ! But if I have a duplicate, why I can't try it, even if it's better ?

Comment: @TheoBendit I also show my try ! Can you consider my opinion ?

Comment: @KReiser Can I write my approach in the linked post instead, Jack also did it for me!

Comment: Closing as duplicate does not necessarily mean that your post is bad. It just marked it as a duplicate, that's all.

Comment: @Jack Okay ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $I_m$ is the integral of $\log^m x$ then integration by parts gives:
$$
I_{m} = x \log^{m} x - m I_{m-1}
$$

by repeated application of this we obtain:

$$
I_m = x( \log^m x - m\log^{m-1} x + m(m-1) \log^{m-2} x - ... +(-1)^m)
$$
which may be written as:
$$
I_m = x\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{m-k} \frac{m!}{k!} \log^k x
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int \ln^{n} x dx = x \ln^{n}x - n\int\ln^{n-1}x dx + C $$

Please see:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xE0Pp4I7PiA

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=e^t$, Then $$I_n=\int \ln^n x~ dx= \int t^n e^t dt~ \mbox{(Int. by parts)}~= t^n e^t -n\int t^{n-1} e^t~ dt = t^n e^t -n I_{n-1}.$$ This is the reduction formula, using which
repeatedly on get the desired result. Lastly, we have $I_0= t$ Or alternatively: $$I_n=x\ln^n x -n\int x \ln ^{n-1}x~ dx\Rightarrow I_n=x \ln^n x-n I_{n-1}, ~~~I_0=x.$$